# Cannot find the "Add" method of the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

1. I created **DLL** project
2. I created `EDMX` and built model from the database
3. I do like

> ```
> MyEntities context = new MyEntities();
> var p = new Product();
> context.Product.Add // and there is no Add method.
> ```

So what's wrong with things I did?

Thanks!

Comment: When you view the EDMX is your Product/Products table there?

Comment: it is probably `context.Add()`

Comment: What about the plural? Does `context.Products.Add(object)` exist? You could also try `context.Add()`

Comment: Make sure you're pluralizing the database object while generating the model from database. It'll separate your entity from collection. Otherwise you'll endup in conflicting references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was because of the some Resharper issue and the normal intellisense is working a little bit slower than it should.

I just added the code

context.Product.Add(p);

and recompiled my project and  it is working.

Comment: please explain better, so when someone else comes along with a similar problem it will help them even more.  thanks

Answer (score 7):

With EF naming conventions, that should be `context.Products.Add()`

The collection of your objects are named with the name of the object plus a "S" so `Product` should create a `Products` collection in the context